# rails 4 rspec use to work and now it fails user.profile is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cancancan

This test used to work, but I can't figure out why is stopped. Now when I run it other_user.profile is equil to nil.

Test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "User" do
 describe "abilities" do
  subject(:ability){ Ability.new(user) }
  let(:other_user) { nil }

  context "not logged in (Guest)" do
    let(:other_user){ build(:user_with_profile) }

    it{ should be_able_to(:show, other_user.profile) }
  end
 end
end
```

Factories:

```
# users.rb factory
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password "secret"
  end

  factory :user_with_profile, parent: :user do
    after(:build) do |user|
    build(:profile, user: user)
  end
end

# profiles.rb factory
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :profile do |f|
    association :user, factory: :user
    f.about { Faker::Lorem.paragraph(2) }
    f.avatar { fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('spec', 'support', 'test.png'), 'image/png') }
  end  
end
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
factory :user_with_profile, parent: :user do
  after(:build) do |user|
    build(:profile, user: user)
  end
end
```

to

```
factory :user_with_profile, parent: :user do
  after(:build) do |user|
    user.profile = build(:profile)
  end
end
```